# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord

Tags: java

i am try to use KafkaConsumer to consume the records, but i got the below exception

```
public void kafkaConsumerRun() {
    Properties prop = getProperties();
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(prop)) {
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
        Schema schema = Common.SCHEMA;
        log.info("SCHEMA = " + schema.toString());
        Map<String, Object> eventMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(pollInterval));
            JSONObject payloadJson = new JSONObject();
            if (records.count() > 0) {
                log.info(records.count() + " records in partition");
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> rec : records) {
                    GenericRecord record = SpecificData.get().deepCopy(schema, rec.value());
                    log.info("Priting Events before camel case conversion : " + record.toString());
                    for (Iterator<Schema.Field> fieldItr = record.getSchema().getFields().iterator(); fieldItr
                            .hasNext();) {
                        String fieldName = fieldItr.next().name();
                        Object value = record.get(fieldName);
                        getFieldName(fieldName, eventMap, value);
                    }
                    log.info("JSON String: " + new JSONObject(eventMap).toString());
                    callOrchestrator(eventMap, payloadJson);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception Caught: ", ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception stack trace should point you at exactly which line is wrong, and it is telling you exactly what is happening:  there is an instance of `String` that you are trying to cast to `GenericRecord`.  Make sure that when you are passing an object as an `Object` that you cast it back to the proper type when you need to.